# Google Playstore send data to Web Server

Tags: php, android

We have an app that checks version using our web server, if our android application does not match the current web server version we will alert the user to update to the google playstore.
The problem is every-time we change the application version we also need to change the server version and if we first upload the server version no one can play because the application is not yet available on google playstore.
now my question is it possible if google send data to our server if our new version that has been uploaded is available on the market because if you upload your application on playstore it needs more time to publish before releasing it to the market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no way to get notified when your update is available. Furthermore, it's not an all-or-nothing question - updates become available at different times in different geographic regions as well.

In essence, updates to your app don't have transactional integrity.